# Return JSON data from Parse Cloud Code to a Decodable Struct in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parse-server, parse-cloud-code, decodable

I'm looking to run a Cloud-Code function from a Swift application and receive an object as a response. The response object from Parse is a standard JSON object as defined below and is not an object stored is Parse. Essentially, I'm looking to end up with an custom object defining the results of a cloud function's execution, not an object stored in the database.

I'm struggling with decoding the CloudCode response on the Swift side of things to a custom object following the `Decodable` protocol.

### Sample Cloud Code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("MyCloudFunc", function(request, response) {
    var results = { 
        "someBooleanProperty": true, 
        "someIntProperty": 1,
    };
    response.success(results);
}
```

### Sample Swift Code

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "MyCloudFunc", withParameters: []) { (result, error) in
    // Printing `result` at this point shows what appears to be a JSON object. 
    guard let data = result as? Data else { return }
    // Whatever type `result` actually is cannot be cast as Data, so we never make it past here.
    guard let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyDecodableStruct, from: data) else { return }
    // DO SOMETHING WITH THE RESULT
}
```

### Decodable Struct

```
struct MyDecodableStruct: Decodable {
    var someBooleanProperty:Bool
    var someIntProperty: Int
}
```

### Question

How can I take that response from the Parse Cloud Code and end up with a decoded object of type `MyDecodableStruct`?

### UPDATE

As suggested in the comments/answers, Parse is returning a Dictionary. I have been able to get everything working with the below; however, I feel there is a better way than double-conversion.

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "MyCloudFunc", withParameters: []) { (result, error) in
    guard let jsonString = result as? String else { return }
    guard let data = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return }
    guard let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyDecodableStruct.self, from: data) else { return }
    // DO SOMETHING WITH RESULT.
}
```

Am I overlooking a way to convert from the `Dictionary` directly `Data` without doing the JSON conversion in-between?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're really getting a JSON string?  My expectation (based on the cloud code shown) is that the `result` of PFCloud.callFunction will be dictionary.  Check `if result is Dictionary<AnyHashable,Any> { print("result is a Dictionary") }`

Answer (score 3):

Part of `PFCloud`'s job is to create generic collection types from the cloud function response.  Since the cloud function is answering a JS object, `PFCloud` should -- without the app noticing -- transmit JSON and parse it before invoking the `callFunction` callback.

So the posted cloud code result will the be a dictionary.  Check to see that with...

```
if result is Dictionary<AnyHashable,Any> {
    print("result is a Dictionary")
}
```

To convert that to the OP struct, add a from-dictionary initializer to it...

```
struct MyDecodableStruct: Decodable {
    var someBooleanProperty:Bool
    var someIntProperty: Int
    init(dictionary: [AnyHashable,Any]) {
        self.someBooleanProperty = dictionary["someBooleanProperty"] as? Bool ?? false
        self.someIntProperty = dictionary["someIntProperty"] as? Int ?? 0
    }
}
```